# Why is my Binding only working one way?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

I am using the following xaml code:

```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Offsets, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="X" Width="90">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding X, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                     Width="70"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

(I know this looks a little sloppy, but I am trying to keep it minimal)

The Offsets property I am binding to is a `public List<Point3D> { get; set;}`. (`using System.Windows.Media.Media3D`).

As such each Point3D has a public X,Y and Z property.

My ListView generates fine, but when I try to change a value of a TextBox, the Datacontext isn't updated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: riteshmeher is right. You can also use `ObservableCollection<Point3D>` which implements this.

Comment: So you are editing the TextBox and the set is not called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about [Point3D Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.point3d(v=vs.110).aspx)
Yes it has XYZ public properties but I don't think it implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: So just put a wrapper class (or struct) on it that implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Tanks, that's what I just did :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably you forgot to implement the Interface [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at your model or viewmodel classes.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your class. Your binding mode is fine. You should be able to see changes.

```
public class YourClassName: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
public ObservableCollection<YourModel> Offsets
    {
        get {return this.offsets;}

        set
        {
            if (value != this.offsets)
            {
                this.offsets= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Offsets");
            }
        }
    }
}
```